# Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (17/06/2014) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character +

Tags: symfony-2.5

Plz take my issue
 -

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (17/06/2014) at
>   position 0 (1): Unexpected character") in
>   ComAkSolutionsSmsUserBundle:Admin\AcademicYear:manageAcademicYear.html.twig
>   at line 16.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker_1').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'years',
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        });
        $('#datetimepicker_2').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'years',
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        });    

    });
</script>
```

Comment: look at this, maybe it'll help

Comment: thank you - isreal altar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php - your error message is a PHP error message, your code snippet is from JavaScript. You must pass the time string with the correct format to the php-function too.

Comment: And if you are passing a valid time string, then what?